# How to filter JSON in JS react

Tags: javascript

Need to filter this JSON file by "subject":

```
  "mailbox":[
                     {
                        "mbname":"johndoe@test.ru",
                        "email_list":[
                            {
                                "recipient":    "john@doe.com",
                                "subject":      "This is a test mail",
                                "from":         "info@example.com",
                                "received":     "17.08.2022",
                                "file_name": "testfile.txt"
                            } ,
                            {
                                "recipient":    "john@doe.com",
                                "subject":      "This is a test mail",
                                "from":         "info@example.com",
                                "received":     "17.08.2022",
                                "file_name": ".testfile.txt"
                            }
                        ]
                        
                        } ]
```

I did it for mbname it make senese how to do it, but i case of email_list.subject.includes(key) it is doesnt work

```
 const filterData = (key, data) => {
  const userOnly = data.filter(({mbname}) => mbname.includes(key));
 
  return userOnly[0];
}
```

Comment: FYI: If you just need a single record you can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that accepts an array, a key, and a value, and then `filter` the array returning each object where the key/value match.

```js
const json = '{"mailbox":[{"mbname":"johndoe@test.ru","email_list":[{"recipient":"john1@doe.com","subject":"Subject1","from":"info@example.com","received":"17.08.2022","file_name":"testfile.txt"},{"recipient":"john2@doe.com","subject":"Subject2","from":"info@example.com","received":"17.08.2022","file_name":".testfile.txt"}]}]}';

const data = JSON.parse(json);

function filter(arr, key, value) {
  return arr.filter(obj => obj[key] === value);
}

const [{ email_list }] = data.mailbox;

console.log(filter(email_list, 'subject', 'Subject1'));
console.log(filter(email_list, 'subject', 'Subject2'));
console.log(filter(email_list, 'recipient', 'john1@doe.com'));
console.log(filter(email_list, 'recipient', 'john2@doe.com'));
console.log(filter(email_list, 'from', 'info@example.com'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't really understood what you mean, but if you want to filter the emails of the `email_list` that contains a certain substring, you may take a shot like this:

```js
const substr = 'hi!';

const email_list = [{
        "recipient":    "john@doe.com",
        "subject":      "This is a test mail",
        "from":         "info@example.com",
        "received":     "17.08.2022",
        "file_name": "testfile.txt"
    }, {
        "recipient":   "john@doe.com",
        "subject":      "This is a test mail, hi!",
        "from":         "info@example.com",
        "received":     "17.08.2022",
        "file_name": ".testfile.txt"
    }
];

const filteredList = email_list.filter(({ subject }) => subject?.includes(substr));

// :)
console.log(filteredList);
```

*Also, if you just need the first data found that includes the specified filter, you may like to use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your objective very well, but with the solution below you will receive the mail whose subject corresponds to the intended one, and the mbname information will be kept.

```
const list = [
                     {
                        "mbname":"johndoe@test.ru",
                        "email_list":[
                            {
                                "recipient":    "john@doe.com",
                                "subject":      "This is a test mail",
                                "from":         "info@example.com",
                                "received":     "17.08.2022",
                                "file_name": "testfile.txt"
                            } ,
                            {
                                "recipient":    "john@doe.com",
                                "subject":      "This is a test mail",
                                "from":         "info@example.com",
                                "received":     "17.08.2022",
                                "file_name": ".testfile.txt"
                            }
                        ]
                        
                        } ];
```

```
const filterToSubject = (data, infoToFilter) =>
  data
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const { email_list = [], ...rest } = curr;
      return [...acc, ...email_list.map((el) => ({ ...rest, ...el }))];
    }, [])
    .filter(({ subject }) => subject.includes(infoToFilter));
```

```
filterToSubject(list, 'This is')
```